# php inserts only last array record into sql

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have working code, which inserts data into csv file. Here is a part of it:

```
if (isset($_POST['array'])) {
        foreach ($_POST['array'] as $loop) {
            $txt = $txt . $loop['name'] . ";" . $loop['email'];
            $txt .="\n";
        }
    }
```

Instead of csv, i would like it to insert data into mysql database, so i have simply changed the code to:

```
    if (isset($_POST['array'])) {
        foreach ($_POST['array'] as $loop) {

            $sql = "insert into persons (Name, Email)
                    values ('" . $loop['name'] . "', '" . $loop['email'] . "')";     
        }
    }
```

Only the last record is saved into the persons table. There are no errors, but all the previous records except last are not inserted. Why?

Comment: Where do you execute the sql statement?

Comment: Also, you do want to [use prepared statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1).

Comment: You're overwriting `$sql` (instead of concatenating) on every iteration of the loop. Last one wins

Comment: Use small case for table column name `Name`, `Email` to `name`,`email`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why it doesn't work is because you never execute your SQL query anywhere.

To execute the query you should first prepare the statement and then bind the params and execute.

```
// Your connection to DB
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'username', 'password', 'dbname');
$mysqli->set_charset('utf8mb4'); // always set the charset


if (isset($_POST['array'])) {
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare('INSERT INTO persons (Name, Email) VALUES (?,?)');
    foreach ($_POST['array'] as $loop) {
        $stmt->bind_param('ss', $loop['name'], $loop['email']);
        $stmt->execute();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Better way is only one time create `insert`

```
if (isset($_POST['array'])) {
    $values = [];
    $sql = "insert into persons (Name, Email) values ";

    foreach ($_POST['array'] as $loop) {
        $values[] = "('" . $conn->real_escape_string($loop['name']) . "', '" . $conn->real_escape_string($loop['email']) . "')";     
    }

    if (!empty($values)) {
        $conn->query($sql . implode(', ', $values));
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that this is still very much prone to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: **Warning:** Your code could still be open to [SQL Injections](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60496/1839439) and you should use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](https://php.net/manual/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](https://php.net/manual/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input! Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/). [Escaping is not enough!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5741187)

Answer (score 1):

Please execute query inside the loop as given below

```
...
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
...

if (isset($_POST['array'])) {
    foreach ($_POST['array'] as $loop) {

        $sql = "insert into persons (Name, Email)
                values ('" . $loop['name'] . "', '" . $loop['email'] . "')";    
        $conn->query($sql);// Query should execute inside loop       

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue inserting JSON arrays into MySQL and fixed it by putting the `mysqli_stmt->execute()` function inside the `foreach`

```
// loop through the array
foreach ($data as $row) {
    echo "Data has been Uploaded successfully <br>";
    // get the project details
    $id = $row['id'];
    $name = $row['name'];
    $togglCid = $row['cid'];
    // execute insert query
    mysqli_stmt_execute($sql);
}
```

This means it executes the code after each loop

Answer (score -1):

If you want to execute the query outside the loop
Try using as following

```
 if (isset($_POST['array'])) {
            $sql="";
            foreach ($_POST['array'] as $loop) {

                $sql .= "insert into persons (Name, Email)
                        values ('" . $loop['name'] . "', '" . $loop['email'] . "');\n";     
        }
    }
```